# ¿Cómo darle el formato deseado a un array asociativo de objetos para ser utilizados en gráficos Highcharts?

Tags: php, highcharts

Estoy trabajando con gráficos Highcharts generando una solicitud `jQuery.get()` desde el gráfico al archivo [temperatura3.php](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/44676047/temperatura3.php). Para que el gráfico funcione correctamente, el JSON debe tener tener el siguiente formato:

```
[{"item": "minima", "data":[["2015-12-28",8.8],["2015-12-29",10.8],["2015-12-30",15.3]]},
{"item": "maxima", "data":[["2015-12-28",28.7],["2015-12-29",27.5],["2015-12-30",31.1]]}]
```

La rutina (resumida) que estoy utilizando para obtener dicho  formato es la siguiente:

```
$minima='{"item": "minima", "data":[';
$maxima='{"item": "maxima", "data":[';

foreach($stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $r)
{
    $minima.='["'. $r['fecha'].'",'.$r['minima'].'],';
    $maxima.='["'. $r['fecha'].'",'.$r['maxima'].'],';
}

$minima.=']}';
$maxima.=']}';

$datos = '['.$minima.','.$maxima.']';
$datos= str_replace(",]", "]", $datos); 
echo json_encode($datos,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

La tabla resumida tiene el siguiente formato

```
id       fecha       maxima  minima  
------  ----------  ------  --------
     1  2015-12-28    28.7       8.8
     2  2015-12-29    27.5      10.8
     3  2015-12-30    31.1      15.3
```

Es eficaz pero no es lo óptimo y menos eficiente. Por lo que intuyo que debe haber alguna forma menos ingenua de hacerlo ya sea a través de un array multidimencional de objetos o alguna solución que no he logrado ver.

Comment: Podrías crear una clase que se encargue de las inserciones y que tenga un `__toString()` para escribir los datos. Implicaría más código, pero sería más abstracta, más limpia, y podría ahorrarte errores (p.e.: que se te olvide poner un corchete o un paréntesis en la cadena)

Comment: Es buena idea utilizar el método  __toString() pero al final sería solo mas ordenado (1 punto a favor) pero seguiría siendo poco eficiente. Estoy convencido que debe haber una forma mas elegante de hacerlo ya que los desarrolladores de Highcharts eligieron ese formato. (En su api solo ponen un ejemplo simple y no abordan estos casos)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una opción como bien dices sería definir tus propios objetos y arrays multidimensionales. Por ejemplo:

```
class TemperaturasTipo {
    public $item = "";
    public $data = array();

    public function __construct($item) {
        $this->item = $item;
    }

    public function addData($fecha, $valor) {
        array_push($this->data, array($fecha, $valor));
    }
}

class Temperaturas {
    public $minimas;
    public $maximas;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->minimas = new TemperaturasTipo("minima");
        $this->maximas = new TemperaturasTipo("maxima");
    }

    public function insertarMinima($fecha, $valor) {
        $this->minimas->addData($fecha, $valor);
    }

    public function insertarMaxima($fecha, $valor) {
        $this->maximas->addData($fecha, $valor);
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return json_encode(array($this->minimas, $this->maximas));
    }
}
```

Y con eso el código de arriba se simplificaría a:

```
$temp = new Temperaturas();

foreach($stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $r)
{
    $temp->insertarMinima($r['fecha'], $r['minima']);
    $temp->insertarMaxima($r['fecha'], $r['maxima']);
}

echo $temp;
```

Comment: Esta bueno, esperaré si hay otras respuestas para comprar soluciones.

Comment: Lo replique y es distinto al formato deseado: echo `json_encode($temp);`Devuelve:    `{"minimas":{"item":"minima","data":{"0":{"0":"2015-12-28","1":"8.8"},"1":{"0":"2015-12-29","1":"10.8"},"2":{"0":"2015-12-30","1":"15.3"}}}`.Eso es más o menos lo que me ha pasado cuando he intentado hacerlo  directamente con arrays asociativos. Pero va por ahí la cosa...

Comment: @EduardoMunizaga llamas a json_encode con parametros? Yo lo llamo sin parametros y me devuelve la cadena correcta (con corchetes)

Comment: Si pero se lo saque y queda mejor aunque con una diferencia que supongo es fácil de resolver: Obtenido: `{"minimas":{"item":"minima","data":[[` v/s Deseado: `{"item": "minima", "data":[[`

Comment: A mí me devuelve esto: `[{"item":"minima","data":[["2012-12-28",8.8],["2012-12-29",10.8],["2012-12-30",15.3]]},{"item":"maxima","data":[["2012-12-28",28.7],["2012-12-29",27.5],["2012-12-30",31.1]]}]`. ¿Puede que sea algo en la configuración de PHP?

Comment: No lo se. te dejo el archivo a ver si ves algo raro. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/44676047/temperatura33.php

Comment: Estás haciendo `json_encode` dos veces (una en el `__toString()` y otra al final). Quita la última porque no hace falta y eso soluciona el problema

Comment: Ahi esta perfecto! Gracias.

Comment: Estimado ya funciona, pero tengo una curiosidad: ¿ Porque en tu ejemplo el Json no retorna los Strip slashes?  [{\"item\": \"minima\", \"data\":[[\"2015-12-28\",8.8] (para este caso me da lo mismo porque solo cambio un parámetro al recepcionarlo)

Comment: Creo que es porque en el caso de la pregunta primero creas la cadena y luego le aplicas el `json_encode` (que escapa las comillas internas); en cambio, en el ejemplo de la respuesta, se aplica `json_encode` directamente al objeto y las cadenas se consideran cadenas y no se escapan